# Does SQL/MED (ISO/IEC 9075-9) defines a writable foreign data wrapper interface

Tags: sql-standard

I just can't find anything about it.

I don't have the paper or draft of the SQL:2011, and have almost only drafts from SQL:2008, 2006, 2003.

Does anyone know if "SQL/MED (ISO/IEC 9075-9)" defines a writable foreign data wrapper interface?

Comment: You can find draft documents for SQL2011 at: http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip. Foreign data wrappers are mentioned in 7IWD2-09-MED-2011-12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does define a writable interface.

Comment: V. short answer - perhaps you could expand on it, with a reference or two?